# Custom landing page with Octopress

Tags: compass-sass, octopress

I've setup Octopress and want to use totally custom styling basically throwing out most of the standard styling that applies to the rest of the site.

I do want to keep reference to all responsive goodness though that is baked in.

What's the best way to setup my custom landing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

http://eduncan911.com

^- My Octopress site.

Blog is at: http://eduncan911.com/blog

Since Octopress uses Jekyll under the skin, it would be better to think about how to accomplish this in terms of Jekyll - and there are many ways to do this.

OT: Personally, I find Octopress' theme layout, includes and customs far too complex and too granular.  They did this to make it highly customable; but in my view, it tightly couples every template to another template.

Now with that said, there are multiple ways to achieve this.  I did answer a very similar question here:

[Creating an octopress theme from a wordpress theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262428/creating-an-octopress-theme-from-a-wordpress-theme)

It's Jekyll: therefore, just go create the page however you want it.  Replace the `/source/index.html` with whatever design, html and css you want.

If you don't want the blog roll, or want to move the "blog to another directory", just move the current `/source/index.html` to, say, `/source/blog/index.html`.  That's it.

As I noted in the answer above, the only import thing is to keep the YAML frontmatter and specify the "layout" as you want to use.  For example, I have a layout called "homepage" that is far different than any other layout.  My `/source/index.html` uses `layout: homepage`.

But even then, you don't even have to use the YAML - create your own raw html file as you see fit.  It will be used when you `rake generate`.  This is what I personally did at first.  Then, I slowly split up the homepage into the `/source/_layouts/homepage.html` and just went from there.  I did not follow Octopress' entire theme at all - just enough to use posts and pages.

Comment: Thanks! Twas a while ago I posted this, really appreciate you taking the time to give such an awesome answer. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, didn't notice the age until I posted.  Was browsing SO and thought, "are there any Octopress questions. I've got a good handle on it now."

Comment: Yeah Nice one! Peeps like you make SO great!